# How to assign async task method to a multicastdelegate parameter

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, delegates, task

I need to assign `async Task` method to a multicastdelegate parameter as follows.

```
protected async Task GridRowSelect(Employee emp)
{
    await Service.SetRowSelect(emp.Id);
}

gridSettings.RowSelect = new EventCallback<Employee>(this, (Action<Employee>)GridRowSelect);
```

But it gives an error.

> 'Task GridRowSelect(Employee) has the wrong return type'

If I change `async Task` to `async void` this is working. But is that the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `async void` is the correct way. The `async void` is [intended specifically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) for making asynchronous event handlers possible. That's the whole reason for its existence. So using it for handling the `RowSelect` event is OK.